# Java Pattern - RegEx not matching for link search

Tags: java, regex

I have a String variable called 'page' that contains the html content of a site page. When I try to search for the link tags using my regex (using Java Pattern) I get no matches yet when I tested my regex online I got many matches for the same website content.

```
..
String pattern = "<a\b[^>]*>(.*?)</a>";
Pattern r = Pattern.compile(pattern);

//page is a String that contains the whole html of a webpage
Matcher m = r.matcher(page);

System.out.println(page);

if(m.find()){
    System.out.println("Found matches");
}
else{
  System.out.println("Found nothing");
}
```

[image]

Comment: In Java, you need to use double backslashes. `\b` is a backspace char.

Comment: Sorry, but it looks like you are using a wrong tool. Use [`jsoup`](http://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/working-with-urls) (at least) to parse HTML.

Comment: You should not use regex for parsing html - see here, perhaps the most famous answer ever on Stackoverflow: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/430885 :)

Comment: But yeah - there is also flavour differences. From your screenshot, looks like the tool you tested, you had set to javascript. Javascript won't regex the same way as your java code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are required to escape the `backslash character` from the `string literal`, in Java as well as in many other programming languages the `\` is used as escape sequence. For regexes, the `\` is also used for escaping purposes.

Basically, you'll need to escape your pattern as follows:

```
String pattern = "a\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/a>";
```

### Working Example:

package SO_35187662;

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class SO_35187662 {

    private static String REG_EX;
    private static String HTML_TEXT;

    static {
        REG_EX = "<a\\b[^>]*>(.*?)<\\/a>";
        HTML_TEXT = "<ul><li class='toclevel-1 tocsection-1'><a href='#Plot'><span class='tocnumber'>1</span> <span class='toctext'>Plot</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-1 tocsection-2'><a href='#Cast'><span class='tocnumber'>2</span> <span class='toctext'>Cast</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-1 tocsection-3'><a href='#Production'><span class='tocnumber'>3</span> <span class='toctext'>Production</span></a><ul><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-4'><a href='#Development'><span class='tocnumber'>3.1</span> <span class='toctext'>Development</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-5'><a href='#Pre-production'><span class='tocnumber'>3.2</span> <span class='toctext'>Pre-production</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-6'><a href='#Casting'><span class='tocnumber'>3.3</span> <span class='toctext'>Casting</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-7'><a href='#Filming'><span class='tocnumber'>3.4</span> <span class='toctext'>Filming</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-8'><a href='#Post-production'><span class='tocnumber'>3.5</span> <span class='toctext'>Post-production</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-9'><a href='#Music'><span class='tocnumber'>3.6</span> <span class='toctext'>Music</span></a></li></ul></li><li class='toclevel-1 tocsection-10'><a href='#Release'><span class='tocnumber'>4</span> <span class='toctext'>Release</span></a><ul><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-11'><a href='#Marketing'><span class='tocnumber'>4.1</span> <span class='toctext'>Marketing</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-12'><a href='#Merchandise'><span class='tocnumber'>4.2</span> <span class='toctext'>Merchandise</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-13'><a href='#Home_media'><span class='tocnumber'>4.3</span> <span class='toctext'>Home media</span></a></li></ul></li><li class='toclevel-1 tocsection-14'><a href='#Reception'><span class='tocnumber'>5</span> <span class='toctext'>Reception</span></a><ul><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-15'><a href='#Box_office'><span class='tocnumber'>5.1</span> <span class='toctext'>Box office</span></a><ul><li class='toclevel-3 tocsection-16'><a href='#Theatrical_run'><span class='tocnumber'>5.1.1</span> <span class='toctext'>Theatrical run</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-3 tocsection-17'><a href='#Commercial_analysis'><span class='tocnumber'>5.1.2</span> <span class='toctext'>Commercial analysis</span></a></li></ul></li><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-18'><a href='#Critical_response'><span class='tocnumber'>5.2</span> <span class='toctext'>Critical response</span></a></li><li class='toclevel-2 tocsection-19'><a href='#Accolades'><span class='tocnumber'>5.3</span> <span class='toctext'>Accolades</span></a><ul><li class='toclevel-3 tocsection-20'><a href='#Top_ten_lists'><span class='tocnumber'>5.3.1</span> <span class='toctext'>Top ten lists</span></a></li></ul></li></ul>";
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(REG_EX);
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(HTML_TEXT);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        } 
    }
}
```